# react-virtualized ArrowKeyStepper List

Tags: javascript, react-virtualized

```
import { List, AutoSizer, ArrowKeyStepper } from 'react-virtualized';

...//      

<div className={classes.listContainer}>
      <ArrowKeyStepper
        mode="cells"
        columnCount={1}
        scrollToColumn={0}
        rowCount={users.length}
        onScrollToChange={({ scrollToRow }) => this.selectRow(scrollToRow)}
      >
        {({ onSectionRendered, scrollToRow = 1 }) => (
          <AutoSizer disableHeight={!autoHeight}>
            {({ width, height }) => (
              <List
                users={users}
                rowCount={users.length}
                rowHeight={cardUsers.rowHeight}
                height={autoHeight ? height : cardUsers.contentHeight}
                width={width}
                rowRenderer={this.renderRow}
                overscanRowCount={5}
                onRowsRendered={onSectionRendered}
                onRowClick={({ index }) => this.selectRow(index)}
                scrollToRow={scrollToRow}
              />
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
        )}
      </ArrowKeyStepper>
    </div>
```

Expected Behavior: arrow up/down would move the selection of an item in the list.
Actual Behavior: nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

use scrollToIndex instead of scrollToRow in List.